# How to get original location of script used for SLURM job?

Tags: bash, variables, path, slurm

I'm starting the SLURM job with script and script must work depending on it's location which is obtained inside of script itself with `SCRIPT_LOCATION=$(realpath $0)`. But SLURM copies script to `slurmd` folder and starts job from there and it screws up further actions.

Are there any option to get location of script used for slurm job before it has been moved/copied?

Script is located in network shared folder `/storage/software_folder/software_name/scripts/this_script.sh` and it must to:

1. get it's own location
2. return the `software_name` folder
3. copy the `software_name` folder to a local folder `/node_folder` on node
4. run another script from copied folder `/node_folder/software_name/scripts/launch.sh`

My script is

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --partition=my_partition_name

# getting location of software_name 
SHARED_PATH=$(dirname $(dirname $(realpath $0)))
# separating the software_name from path
SOFTWARE_NAME=$(basename $SHARED_PATH)
# target location to copy project
LOCAL_SOFTWARE_FOLDER='/node_folder'
# corrected path for target
LOCAL_PATH=$LOCAL_SOFTWARE_FOLDER/$SOFTWARE_NAME

# Copying software folder from network storage to local
cp -r $SHARED_PATH $LOCAL_SOFTWARE_FOLDER
# running the script
sh $LOCAL_PATH/scripts/launch.sh
```

It runs perfectly, when I run it on the node itself (without using SLURM) via: `sh /storage/software/scripts/this_script.sh`.

In case of running it with SLURM as 
`sbatch /storage/software/scripts/this_script.sh` it is assigned to one of nodes, but:

- before run it is copied to `/var/spool/slurmd/job_number/slurm_script` and it screws everything up since `$(dirname $(dirname $(realpath $0)))` returns `/var/spool/slurmd`

Is it possible to get original location (`/storage/software_folder/software_name/`) inside of script when it is started with SLURM?

P.S. All machines are running Fedora 30 (x64)

**UPDATE 1**

There was a suggestion to run as `sbatch -D /storage/software_folder/software_name ./scripts/this_script.sh` and use the `SHARED_PATH="${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}"` inside of script itself.
But it raise the error `sbatch: error: Unable to open file ./scripts/this_script.sh`.

Also, I tried to use absolute paths:
`sbatch -D /storage/software_folder/software_name /storage/software_folder/software_name/scripts/this_script.sh`. It tries to run, but:

- in such case it uses specified folder for creating output file only
- software still doesn't want to run
- attempt to use `echo "${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}"` inside of script prints `/home/username_who_started_script` instead of `/storage/software_folder/software_name`

Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE 2:**
Also tried to use `#SBATCH --chdir=/storage/software_folder/software_name` inside of script, but in such case `echo "${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}"` returns `/home/username_who_started_script`or  `/` (if run as root)

**UPDATE 3**

Approach with `${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}` worked only if task is ran as:

```
cd /storage/software_folder/software_name
sbatch ./scripts/this_script.sh
```

But it doesn't seem to be a proper solution. Are there any other ways?

**SOLUTION**

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --partition=my_partition_name

# check if script is started via SLURM or bash
# if with SLURM: there variable '$SLURM_JOB_ID' will exist
# `if [ -n $SLURM_JOB_ID ]` checks if $SLURM_JOB_ID is not an empty string
if [ -n $SLURM_JOB_ID ];  then
    # check the original location through scontrol and $SLURM_JOB_ID
    SCRIPT_PATH=$(scontrol show job $SLURM_JOBID | awk -F= '/Command=/{print $2}')
else
    # otherwise: started with bash. Get the real location.
    SCRIPT_PATH=$(realpath $0)
fi

# getting location of software_name 
SHARED_PATH=$(dirname $(dirname $(SCRIPT_PATH)))
# separating the software_name from path
SOFTWARE_NAME=$(basename $SHARED_PATH)
# target location to copy project
LOCAL_SOFTWARE_FOLDER='/node_folder'
# corrected path for target
LOCAL_PATH=$LOCAL_SOFTWARE_FOLDER/$SOFTWARE_NAME

# Copying software folder from network storage to local
cp -r $SHARED_PATH $LOCAL_SOFTWARE_FOLDER
# running the script
sh $LOCAL_PATH/scripts/launch.sh
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the initial (i.e. at submit time) location of the submission script from `scontrol` like this:

```
scontrol show job "$SLURM_JOB_ID" | awk -F= '/Command=/{print $2}'
```

So you can replace the `realpath $0` part with the above. This will only work within a Slurm allocation of course. So if you want the script to work in any situation, you will need some logic like:

```
if [ -n "${SLURM_JOB_ID:-}" ] ; then
THEPATH=$(scontrol show job "$SLURM_JOB_ID" | awk -F= '/Command=/{print $2}')
else
THEPATH=$(realpath "$0")
fi
```

and then proceed with

```
SHARED_PATH=$(dirname "$(dirname "${THEPATH}")")
```

Comment: I was moving to logic in a similar way, but I was planning to use `-z` key in `if` statement alike: `if [ -z $SLURM_JOB_ID ]; then ...`. Is there a significant difference between those options?

Comment: Thanks I fixed the typo. As for `-z` and `-n` they are basically the opposite one of another, so you can use that and inverse the `then` and `else` clauses.

Comment: awk didn't work for me, my command has parameters after the script path. I had to change the awk part this way: `scontrol show job $SLURM_JOBID |grep 'Command=' |sed -r s/'.*Command=(.+\.sh).*'/'\1'/`. Probably there is a quicker way to do the same with awk, but I know sed better.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same in an array job, the accepted answer from [@damienfrancois](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991068/9539512) works well for all jobs except the jobid which is same as ArrayJobId. Just piping awk command to head command would do the trick

```
scontrol show job $SLURM_JOBID | awk -F= '/Command=/{print $2}' | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In script, get `SHARED_PATH` as `SHARED_PATH="${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}"`

Submit script as `sbatch -D /storage/software ./scripts/this_script.sh`

See [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html).

From referred page:

`-D`

> Set the working directory of the batch script to directory before it
>   is executed. The path can be specified as full path or relative path
>   to the directory where the command is executed.

`SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR`

> The directory from which sbatch was invoked or, if applicable, the directory specified by the -D, --chdir option.

**P.S.** Above is from Version 19.05 doc.
While looking in to archive, referring Ver. 18.x (esp. 18.08), it doesn't mention the same. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190214141524/https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html)

`SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR`.

> The directory from which sbatch was invoked.

Comment: Tried. Still the same problem.

Comment: Tried also:
`sbatch -D /storage/software_folder/software_name/scripts/ ./this_script.sh`
`sbatch -D /storage/software_folder/software_name/scripts/ /storage/software_folder/software_name/scripts//this_script.sh`
and replacing of `-D` with `--chdir=` and quoting path. Didn't help. It doesn't accept changing the directory.

Comment: For some reason, if use `echo ${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}` inside of script it prints `home/username` to output file

Comment: which `slurm` version, you are using?

Comment: 18.  Does it really matter?

Answer (score 0):

In case of using SLURM's
`#SBATCH --array 1-N`, [@damienfrancois](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991068/9539512) works if the first path of the return argument is taken. The reply from [@Karthik Govindappa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66960850/13875472) did not work for me, but this approach https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53315 resulting in

```bash
IFS=' ' read -r THEPATH _ <<< $(scontrol show job "$SLURM_JOB_ID" | awk -F= '/Command=/{print $2}')
```