# How can I output my SBATCH options in the .out file OR How to echo commented lines in bash

Tags: bash, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I'm fairly new to HPC computing using the SLURM Workload Manager and hence have yet to find a reliable working routine. As of now, I have a jobscript with a bunch of #SBATCH flags that I modify whenever I do another calculation.
This includes the total run time and the number of nodes / tasks / CPUs.

Since I'm still gaining experience, I would like to save the chosen options for reference in the standard .out - file produced by SLURM. I have found on the [sbatch manual page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) a few options in the filename pattern section to at least remember the jobname, but what I really want is a complete list of all the set #SBATCH flags.

My current workaround goes like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --time=0:20:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH -p normal
#SBATCH -q cont
#SBATCH -J crosscorr
#SBATCH --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out

echo "#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --time=0:20:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH -p normal
#SBATCH -q cont
#SBATCH -J crosscorr
#SBATCH --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
"
```

and is obviously not satisfying and also prone to typos. Since the SLURM manager relies on code that bash does not see (as it's commented out), I see no easy fix using the bash language for this. Neither did I find any hints using the sbatch options.

Maybe there even is another way to save those options. I know that I might grep these desired options using a automatized seff inquiry, but I wish there would be an easier way, because the Job ID is only assigned after job submission.

Comment: what about just starting you script with a `head` of the current script?

Comment: with the script name inquiry automatized like in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991068/5239503

Comment: actually a great idea, ty, solves my problem! should have thought of it on my own :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `slurm` is but you appear to be using a construct `#SBATCH` to set some options for it within what is otherwise a `bash` script so maybe you could populate a bash array with the options and then both print them and `#SBATCH` them, e.g. (the spaces at the start of the here-document lines being read by `readarray` must be tabs, not blanks):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t opts <<-'!'
        --ntasks=2
        --cpus-per-task=4
        -time=0:20: 00
        --mem=4G
        -p normal
        -q cont
        -J crosscorr
        --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
!

for opt in "${opts[@]}"; do
    printf '#SBATCH %s\n' "$opt"
    #SBATCH "$opt"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --time=0:20:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH -p normal
#SBATCH -q cont
#SBATCH -J crosscorr
#SBATCH --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
```

You can use that to either replace your current script to set `#SBATCH` if that works or to generate another script to replace your current script:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t opts <<-'!'
        --ntasks=2
        --cpus-per-task=4
        -time=0:20: 00
        --mem=4G
        -p normal
        -q cont
        -J crosscorr
        --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
!

printf '#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\n'
printf '#SBATCH %s\n' "${opts[@]}" | tee '/dev/stderr'
```

```
$ cat slurm.sh
cat: slurm.sh: No such file or directory
```

```
$ ./tst.sh > slurm.sh
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --time=0:20:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH -p normal
#SBATCH -q cont
#SBATCH -J crosscorr
#SBATCH --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
```

```
$ cat slurm.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --time=0:20:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH -p normal
#SBATCH -q cont
#SBATCH -J crosscorr
#SBATCH --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
```

or it looks like your file of `#SBATCH` directives is used by a tool named `opts` so maybe you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t opts <<-'!'
        --ntasks=2
        --cpus-per-task=4
        -time=0:20: 00
        --mem=4G
        -p normal
        -q cont
        -J crosscorr
        --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
!

sbatch <(
    printf '#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\n'
    printf '#SBATCH %s\n' "${opts[@]}" | tee '/dev/stderr'
)
```

to use command substitution to provide a "file" of `#SBATCH` directives to `sbatch`, or if `sbatch` requires a regular file:

```
$ cat ./tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

readarray -t opts <<-'!'
        --ntasks=2
        --cpus-per-task=4
        -time=0:20: 00
        --mem=4G
        -p normal
        -q cont
        -J crosscorr
        --output=jobscript_slurmout/R-%j.%x.out
!

printf '#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\n'
printf '#SBATCH %s\n' "${opts[@]}" | tee "$tmp" >&2

sbatch "$tmp"
```

to create the file of `#SBATCH` commands, call `sbatch` with that file as an argument, then remove that file.

all the the `| tee ...`s above are just so you can see the `#SBATCH` directives being generated as I think that's mainly what you wanted.